# Does anybody can help me with sound for my interactive concept? (urgent)

Tags: design, film, interactive

I'm studying communication design and my final project is an inteactive concept for learning russian. I tryied to make an appropriate sound, but I failed. Does anyone can help me with it? I'm frustrated.

Comment: @Vik, maybe if your describe the project a little more you'll get someone interested in it
Cheers!

Comment: Filipe is right. At the very least, we need to know what you consider an "appropriate sound" to be.